# Cronjob for localhost xampp on MacOS

Tags: php, cron, xampp, localhost

I setting on the host this cronjob and it work but, I need local and dont know how it work

my code is: 
1 step 
open terminal and type

> crontab -e

2 step

> write this code

```
* * * * * wget --spider -O - /Applications/XAMPP/xampfiles/htdocs/mysite.local/index.php/cron/comment >/dev/null 2>&1
```

3 step

> save and close file.

but not work... where is problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the absolute path of the script.

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/wget --spider -O - http://insta.local/cron/comment >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: is not work ... maybe exist document how create cron for localhost xampp?

Comment: can you run this command in terminal `wget --spider -O - /Applications/XAMPP/xampfiles/htdocs/mysite.local/index.php/cron/comment`? what is the output

Comment: then you should first install `wget`. Try `apt install wget` in terminal

Comment: when I install wget and input  `wget --spider -O - /Applications/XAMPP/xampfiles/htdocs/mysite.local/index.php/cron/comment` result is **Scheme missing.**

Comment: what you want to do with the script?

Comment: I buy GramEasy https://codecanyon.net/item/grameasy-instagram-automatic-tool/20292050?s_rank=18 . but I instaled it on localhost and need cronjob for work any tasks

Comment: you need to access it through http protocol, but not file protocol, otherwise it won't run any scripting language. try to set your server up first, and check `http://localhost/cron/comment` run properly, then setup the cronjob `wget --spider -O - http://localhost/cron/comment`

Comment: I use xampp and instaled it with domain http://insta.local - it work, maybe use wget --spider -O - http : // insta.local/cron/comment ?

Comment: yes, only if you have correctly configured apache server `ServerName` or `VirtualHost`

Comment: ServerName and VirtualHost work, but I dont know how correctly setting cron with local link on MacOS...,

Comment: unless it supports cli, you could run `/opt/lampp/bin/php /Applications/XAMPP/xampfiles/htdocs/mysite.local/index.php/cron/comment`, otherwise you need to run the script through http protocol